# angular ng-grid can we just allow to group some columns and let other columns not to be groupable

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

in my grid option, I let showGroupPanel: true
So the grid can group all columns but  I only want to group some of them. Is there any way to deal with this problem?

Answer (score 1):

As per their [docs](http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/) you can change the default value 'groupable' to false in your column definition. Something like this:

```
$scope.gridOptions = { 
    data: 'myData',
    showGroupPanel: true,
    columnDefs: [{field:'Name', displayName:'Col Name', groupable: false}, 
                 {field:'Value', displayName:'Value', groupable: true}]
    };
```